# ListView Crashes App on scrolling Using ViewHolder

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, custom-adapter

My app crashes when i scroll up and down for a couple times in a ListView which is feed by a customAdapter which extends a baseAdapter.

there is also a problem that when i scroll up and down that info in the rows change places sometimes and sometimes disappear that is only

LOGCAT

```
04-02 00:30:25.390: I/System.out(4461): Not a DRM File, opening notmally
04-02 00:30:25.445: I/System.out(4461): buffer returned 
04-02 00:30:25.531: I/dalvikvm-heap(4461): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 12582928-byte allocation
04-02 00:30:25.570: E/dalvikvm-heap(4461): Out of memory on a 12582928-byte allocation.
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41135508 self=0x40f0a930
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   | sysTid=4461 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074736944
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   | schedstat=( 11607757611 1931762655 12518 ) utm=1084 stm=75 core=1
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:619)
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:385)
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFile(BitmapFactory.java:418)
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at com.android.moha.MainActivity$MyCustomAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:754)
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2445)
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1769)
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.widget.ListView.fillUp(ListView.java:706)
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:645)
04-02 00:30:25.570: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:5530)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.widget.AbsListView.scrollIfNeeded(AbsListView.java:3413)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3906)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7340)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2179)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1914)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2185)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1928)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2113)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1466)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2468)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2061)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7525)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3368)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3300)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4392)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4370)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4474)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:163)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4442)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4493)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:523)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
04-02 00:30:25.578: I/dalvikvm(4461):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-02 00:30:25.617: E/InputEventReceiver(4461): Exception dispatching input event.
```

CustomAdapter getView

```
  @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(l, null);
            holder  = new ViewHolder();

            holder.id = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
            holder.name = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.price = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.description = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            holder.button = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.order);
            holder.quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);

            if (a == itemsList){
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu_icon);

            }


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }

        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.id.setText(getId(getItem(position)));
        holder.name.setText(getName(getItem(position)));
        holder.price.setText("£ " + getPrice(getItem(position)));
        holder.description.setText(getDesc(getItem(position)));
        String path = getImgPath(getItem(position));
        if(a==itemsList){

            final String quantity = "1";

            sign = "+";

            if(path.equals("") || path.equals(null)){
                //holder.img.setImageDrawable(defaul);
                holder.img.setContentDescription("default");
            }
            else{
                Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
                holder.img.setImageBitmap(bm);
                holder.img.setContentDescription("set");
            }


        holder.img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @SuppressLint("NewApi")
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final ImageView full = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullScreen);
                full.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                full.setEnabled(true);

                full.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                full.setImageDrawable(holder.img.getDrawable());

                full.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);


                full.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        full.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        full.setEnabled(false);
                        return true;

                    }
                });

            }
        });
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(new android.view.View.OnClickListener(){
             public void onClick(View v) {
              //System.out.println("id" + v.getId());
              //System.out.println("bid" + R.id.order);
                // System.out.println("hell :" + lv.getItemAtPosition(position));
                 //System.out.println("hell :" + lv.getItemAtPosition(position));

              HashMap<String, String> map = itemsList.get(position);
            // System.out.println("items :" + lv.getAdapter().getItem(position));
             //System.out.println("orders :" + orderList.toString());

          if(v.getId() == R.id.order)
         {
              HashMap<String, String> hsh = map;

              String ss = null ;

              boolean done = false;
              for(int i=0; orderList.size()>i; i++){
                  HashMap<String, String> s = orderList.get(i);
                  ss= s.get(TAG_ID).toString();
                 if ( ss.equalsIgnoreCase(getItem(position).get(TAG_ID).toString()))
                  {
                      int foo = Integer.parseInt(s.get(TAG_QUANTITY).toString());
                      s.put(TAG_QUANTITY,( "" + (foo+1)));
                      done=true;
                      break;
                  }

              }
              if(!done)
              {
                  hsh.put(TAG_QUANTITY, quantity);
                  orderList.add(hsh);
              }


              //Log.d("Selected : ", orderList.toString());
            //  ListAdapter order = new MyCustomAdapter(1,orderList,R.layout.list_item);
              // updating listview
             // list1.setAdapter(order);
             // list11.setAdapter(order);

            ((MyCustomAdapter)  list1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            ((MyCustomAdapter)  list11.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                      Float fo = Float.parseFloat(map.get(TAG_PRICE).toString());
                      Float total = Float.parseFloat(t.getText().toString());

                      //System.out.println("heeeeeeeeeeeeeere :" +fo);
                      t.setText(""+ String.format("%.2f", (fo+total)));
                      totalll = Float.parseFloat(t.getText().toString());
              }
        }
      });
        }
        else
        {                   
            sign = "-";
            if (value == 1)
            {
                holder.quantity.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            ListView l = list1;
            if(((Button) findViewById(R.id.handle)).isPressed())
            {
                l = list11;
            }else{l = list1;}
            final SwipeDetector swipeDetector = new SwipeDetector();
            l.setOnTouchListener(swipeDetector);
            l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        if (swipeDetector.swipeDetected()){                                                               
                              Float fo = Float.parseFloat((getItem(position).get(TAG_PRICE)).toString());
                              Float Quant = Float.parseFloat((getItem(position).get(TAG_QUANTITY)).toString());
                              Float total = Float.parseFloat(t.getText().toString());
                              //System.out.println("heeeeeeeeeeeeeere :" +fo);
                              orderList.remove(getItem(position));
                              t.setText(""+ String.format("%.2f", (total-(fo*Quant))));
                    //remove        //  ListAdapter order = new MyCustomAdapter(1,orderList,R.layout.list_item);
                    //remove        //  list1.setAdapter(order);
                    //remove        //  list11.setAdapter(order);
                              ((MyCustomAdapter)  list1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                              ((MyCustomAdapter)  list11.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                            } 


                     }
            });
            holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                 public void onClick(View v) {
                 // System.out.println("id " + v.getId());
                 // System.out.println("bid " + R.id.order);
                  HashMap<String, String> map = getItem(position);


              if(v.getId() == R.id.order)
             {

                  if ( orderList.contains(getItem(position)) ){
                      System.out.println("item :" +getItem(position));
                      //holder.quantity.setText("q");
                      int foo = Integer.parseInt(map.get(TAG_QUANTITY).toString());

                      map.put(TAG_QUANTITY, "" + (foo-1));
                      if((foo-1)==0)
                      {
                          orderList.remove(getItem(position));
                      }

                  }

                 // ListAdapter order = new MyCustomAdapter(1,orderList,R.layout.list_item);
                          // updating listview
                //        list1.setAdapter(order);
                //        list11.setAdapter(order);
                  ((MyCustomAdapter)  list1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                  ((MyCustomAdapter)  list11.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();

                          Float fo = Float.parseFloat(map.get(TAG_PRICE).toString());
                          Float total = Float.parseFloat(t.getText().toString());

                          //System.out.println("heeeeeeeeeeeeeere :" +fo);
                          t.setText(""+ String.format("%.2f", (total-fo)));
                  }
            }
          });
            holder.button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                      Float fo = Float.parseFloat((getItem(position).get(TAG_PRICE)).toString());
                      Float Quant = Float.parseFloat((getItem(position).get(TAG_QUANTITY)).toString());
                      Float total = Float.parseFloat(t.getText().toString());
                      //System.out.println("heeeeeeeeeeeeeere :" +fo);
                      orderList.remove(getItem(position));
                      t.setText(""+ String.format("%.2f", (total-(fo*Quant))));
                      ((MyCustomAdapter) list1.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                      ((MyCustomAdapter) list11.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }


        if(a==orderList){holder.quantity.setText(getQuant(getItem(position)));}
        if(sign=="-"){holder.button.setText(sign);}
        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem? Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to cover all info cases when set data on holder ,

I mean some time if first item have not "description" on data row then you scroll down and then up this item will set "description" from other row.

Just check your if statements when `holder ==null` & when `holder !=null` and check every item if has value and if not set default value for it.

I hope the answer help you

Comment: doesn't seem to be the problem. for some reason still working